# Container views in UIScrollView not resizing according to content in iOS8.4

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

In my application I'm creating a settings-like view where the user can set his/her preferences. The different sections in the settings view are rather complex, with certain sections containing table views, table views with expandable cells, etc. I decided to use an approach where each section would be represented with a container view, so that I could separate the logic for each section. I then stack these container views in a scroll view.

**The problem:**

On iOS7, this approach works perfectly, and I get my container views stack up nicely, resized to the space they need to show all content.

However, on iOS8.4, all my container views get squashed to 0 height, and I'm left with an empty view.

**Additional notes**:

I use storyboard for creation of the view.

I use a mixed scroll view method. That is, in my scroll view I have one UIView pinned to all edges, and width set to the my view controllers main view. I then put my content views in this view.

I have made sure all constraints needed are set for the container views. Also, I have not set any height constraint on the container views (so that they would get their own intrinsic from the content). I have set a placeholder height constraint though, to simplify things while working in the storyboard editor. I have also tried to remove the constraint completely, but to no avail.

I have made sure all constraints are set for the content of the container views as well.

Again, this method works perfectly in iOS7. Could anyone point me in the right direction to what might have changed?

Thank you

Comment: Hi
I'm facing the same problem.
Did you find a solution ?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. In the end I ditched the whole idea with container views and put everything in UIViews. I would love to hear if you find the solution to this though!

Comment: Hi
Yes I finally solved this issue by re-defining all constraints in the view presenting the container as well as in the container view.
Basically the constraints in the container should be all defined (from the most top view pinned to the top of the container, to the most bottom view that should be pinned to the bottom of the container).
With the above, the container resizes according to its containt.

I also added a callback (once the container has loaded its data), to the parent in order to pass the new height of the container and update the container height constraint in the parent.